# Fill both vertical and horizontal space using flexbox

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have a web interface with several boxes of indeterminate height and fixed width (33.3%) which are arranged in a flexbox. I would like to fill the entire space before creating a new row, unlike my example does:

http://jsfiddle.net/dshb0eaw/1/

HTML:

```
 <div class="flex container">
    <div class="flex item">First box</div>
    <div class="flex item">Second box</div>
    <div class="flex item three">This box is higher than the others</div>
    <div class="flex item">Another box in the next row - can I get this one below box one?</div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}


.flex.container {
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: flex;
    -webkit-flex-wrap: wrap;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    width: 250px;
    border: 1px solid green;
    align-items: flex-start;
    -webkit-align-items: flex-start;
}
.flex.item {
    flex: 1 0 auto;
    -webkit-flex: 1 0 auto;
    border: 1px solid red;
    width: 33.3%;
    max-width: 33.3%;
}

.flex.item.three {
   height: 250px;
}
```

I read about some workaround with multiple wrapper containers, one for the vertical and one for the horizontal filling, but I'm not sure if this could work for me, since my boxes are of indeterminate height when I create them and their height might change during usage.

I know there are JavaScript-based solutions like masonry, which I already tried, but I wonder if there are CSS-only solutions to this.

Comment: I'm afraid you won't be able to achieve that with Flexbox. In fact, I am pretty certain you cannot do that with pure CSS at all, at least not for dynamic element heights. It _might_ be possible with [CSS regions](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/archive/html5/articles/css3-regions.html), but I cannot say that for certain, and it's still far on the horizon anyway.